# sql server 2012 Msg 3286

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, backup

Good day .

Please help me understand the situation . The SQL Server 2012 has a base with a group filestream ( base documents from sharepoint).

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64)
Feb October 2012 19:39:15
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing ( 64 -bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601 : Service Pack 1 ) (Hypervisor)
```

Recently pobilas base magically , I was able to restore it without losing data and without the use of backups .
CheckDB goes well , as with the parameter skip errors associated with filestream, and without it .
But after that there was a problem creating a backup, indicates an error , the description of which I have not found anywhere else.

> Msg 3286 , Level 16 , State 1 , Line 1 Backup failed because there is
>   a mismatch in file metadata for file 65537 . Msg 3013 , Level 16 ,
>   State 1 , Line 1 BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I can not understand what "file 65537 " in this context . blobnumber, BlobID or that of another .
Maybe someone encountered or tell which way to drip . I would be very grateful.